# How do I implement a horizontally populated DataGrid (with the headers on the left instead of at the top)?

Tags: apache-flex, layout, datagrid, header

I am trying to find an easy and robust way to override the default layout of DataGrid and populate its values in a left-right fashion.  To illustrate:

My data model is an array of: {a: xxx1..n, b: yyy1..n, c: zzz1..n}
The default DataGrid component will lay this out as:

```
a      b      c
xxx1   yyy1   zzz1
xxx2   yyy2   zzz2
xxxn   yyyn   zzzn
```

etc.

With "a", "b", and "c" as the headers, and x, y, z being their values for each object in the dataProvider.

Now I want to lay this out *horizontally* like so:

```
a    xxx1    xxx2    xxxn
b    yyy1    yyy2    yyyn
c    zzz1    zzz2    zzzn
```

I've searched around for an answer but haven't hit on anything.  Perhaps I'm just using the wrong keyword searches...

Regardless, if anyone knows a solution to this, be it as mundane as a property setting I've somehow missed, or a 3rd party component, etc. I would be very grateful!

ps: Eventually, this must be entirely tab-enabled and cell-editable.  If you have an esoteric solution involving a multi-field itemRenderer, please keep this in mind.  I mention this because I have attempted such a solution and have failed to penetrate DataGrid's Unfailing Field of Tab Vitiation (ie DataGrid seems to override tab functionality inside its itemRenderer, forcibly setting focus to the next renderer/editor).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible.
Normally, you can manage this with skin classes (for a sparkPanel). There are a nice tutorial from adobe (flex in a week).

In flex hero (the prerelease of flex 5), the datagrid is also implement in spark. I think, then this will be possible.

BR
Frank

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Yeah, I had a bad feeling about this not being possible.  It's a shame, really. I have frequently gotten requests from clients to convert Excel apps into Flex apps since Flex 2.0.  But they don't want the basic interface to change (ie: they want an Excel spreadsheet implemented in Flex).  I have made various work-arounds in the past and have seen some 3rd party solutions, but was hoping for something definitive by now.  Looking forward to upgrading to Spark...